# Laravel conditionally eager load, with or where query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I've got this query:

```
    $paginated = File::whereIn('model_id', $channelRules->pluck('id'))
        ->with('campaignChannelRule.channel.channel')
        ->where('model_type', 'campaign_channel_rule')
        ->orWhere(function($query) use($campaign) {
            $query->where('model_type', 'campaign')->where('model_id', $campaign->id);
        })
        ->paginate(15);
```

The problem is that when a file is of `model_type` `campaign`, I do not want to eager load `->with('campaignChannelRule.channel.channel')`.

How can I achieve this?

Thankyou

Answer (score -2):

I think it's because the wrong syntax of the query, try this one:

```
$paginated = File::with('campaignChannelRule.channel.channel')
        ->whereIn('model_id', $channelRules->pluck('id'))
        ->where(function ($w) use ($campaign) {
            $w->where('model_type', 'campaign_channel_rule')
                ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($campaign) {
                    $query->where('model_type', 'campaign')->where('model_id', $campaign->id);
                });
            })
        ->paginate(15);
```